# Rails: undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

category/show.html.erb

```
<body class="home">
<% @category.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
    <%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory.id %>
<% end %>
```

Throws
    NoMethodError in Category#show 
    undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class

The URL is http://example.com:3000/category/11

Routes.rb

```
FirstApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'category#index'
  resources :category 
end
```

Category controller

```
class CategoryController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end    

  def new
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find params[:id]
  end
end
```

Subcategory controller is empty

```
class SubcategoryController < ApplicationController

  def create
  end

  def new
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

The method category.subcategories works in the console. I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: what does your relationships look like in your models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory %>
```

When you pass `subcategory.id` as a second argument to this method, Rails try to guess the path from `Fixnum` you passed. Since it's impossible, the error is raised.

You should also add

```
resources :subcategories
```

to your routes.rb and rename your `SubcategoryController` to `SubcategoriesController`.

and in `SubcategoriesController#show` should be:

```
@subcategory = Subcategory.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: @darioshanghai you messed up a little bit. ;) I edited my answer.

Comment: Your edit helped, I had the naming convention all wrong. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

could you please try this

```
 <% @category.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
   <%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory_path(subcategory) %>
 <% end %>
```

and in controller hope you have a model subcategory with `many to many` relationship with `category`

```
def show
  @category = SubCateogry.find params[:id]
end
```

In routes

```
resources :subcategories
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory.id %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory %>
```